# Android Java seemingly random strange scrambled network/file output

Tags: java, android, file-io, network-programming

We are downloading three files: file.html, file.css and file.js from a Web API server.

The files always have the same names and the old files are removed before downloading the new ones.

Our problem is that sometimes, after between 3 and 10 downloads, one, two or all of the files will return scrambled.

As you can see in the code below, we output the first byte of the input stream.

For example, the first line of the **html** file is: `<!--DontRemoveThisLine-->`

When it fails, it gives us a string starting with:

```
????????????Zmo8.Iu1.s~*hJ~
e]}Do gy#c˺f=K-
          ]G3{4=yF;Qck,H [1~ھ4c!hJKŵ8o/N }+5eAvɸoQH/ȳdRE4ߝXRHS'q$s6n^d>&-$#[ԑn{    B&\0/L0R)\8K;\Ila?NԘǓ;25I)8*ܵ]*    r傋\8
          ,-!ۡ"y*v;qgQ?/5Abs/oK綇STK    ƣ4; +w44ٕS%֊_>5"rE-pm[!\?O]'rky2lC~&R{&Cb
          NoҵBԗte!}Y3l̩iTrYvSC4[A_q}#<ý$ndŪ9j[֛>:{2/s1if?k/R^Ă3σ
```

The first line in the **js** file is: `//DontRemoveThisLine`

When it fails:

```
????????????ܽywǵ|w
EܓXeN<%c; &1??%]U]=@r޹o=T׸kOr:5/v_??io?48{vy/,:jŢH.?{zљޯRc:ӽEM-"vOo7~7Fq?[|%Tsˆbw"~]9[o>n[w6ߝgoUFe9ݙ/`C{4|Jy]~$?ឦUUGxqe]טQ%\(~{pv"KS|5K_vnQhybZFvu1eʋ=9Utzw}_|qIPr1Sk*vܝ_MtqIp1+]{c
```

And more of the same with the **css** file.

**Worth noting is that the scrambled string will always be the same for each file, implying that the character's aren't random, and that something else is happening.**

It looks like a network or encoding issue, but we have replicated it on other networks, on other devices and from other web service providers. The files are normally served via HTTPS, but we've tried getting them from other sources with the same result.

We also have an iOS application running the same actions from the same server, which never have any issues.

Does anyone have any idea why the files are seemingly randomly scrambled?

Here's the relevant code excerpt.

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
    }

    // download the file
    input = connection.getInputStream();

    output = new FileOutputStream(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + sUrl[1]);

    byte data[] = new byte[4096];
    long total = 0;
    int count;
    int i = 0;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        if (i == 0) {
            String str = new String(data);
            System.out.println("----- file " + sUrl[0] + " first line: " + str + "------");
        }
        i++;
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried replicating this problem using some other method like wget/curl ?

Comment: We have learnt that the issue is solved in a clean project, which would imply that we have a memory leak or something alike?

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. Are you willing to post the address to these files?

Comment: @quinnjn Sorry, I can not do that. We are currently trying isolate parts of the app until our data fetch starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the reason by isolating different parts of the app.

Our problem was the gravatar-android library used in combination with the picasso image downloading library. They were used in a different part of the app.

It seems that either one of them, or our implementation of them, had a memory leak.

Thanks to anyone who spent time on our question.